# Search in Issues feature gone from GitHub?

Tags: search, github, issue-tracking

Not sure when it happened, before the [change](https://github.com/blog/1529-repository-next) or after, but I'm not able to find a search box for searching in issues anymore. Has it been relocated, or it's gone?

Comment: It's integrated in the top search bar.

Comment: which is not very intuitive, there should be an extra button on the right where the repository options are. Reminds me of the "edit" repository name that rarely somebody found (now changed).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Any search you do in the main search field (preceded with "**This repository**") when you are in a GitHub repo page will return:

- result in code
- *and* issues

Note: The shortcut <kbd>/</kbd> will focus on the search field and search within the context of a repository.
Note: that shortcut doesn't work with a french keyboard on Firefox. And it only works if I type ':' (again on a French Keyboard) in Chrome. So your mileage may vary. With US locale, this should work fine.

[image: add search]

Note that in 2022 (9 years later), there is a command palette, and you can [customize the keyboard shortcuts](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-03-customizing-command-palette-keyboard-shortcuts-beta/).

Answer (score 2):

When browsing a repository, you can use the "/" shortcut (just type the character) to easily search issues (as well as the code.) There are a lot of really helpful shortcuts (i.e. "gi", which transports you to a repos issues list.)

Type "?" to get a list of shortcuts for a particular context.

Comment: Didn't saw your answer. +1. Thank you for the edit. It doesn't fully work for me, but still, the sortcut is (in theory) there.

Comment: Don't you hate when a specific keyboard layout is required for shortcuts to work?